# How to refer AWS access key(secret key) in cloud-init without hard coding

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to write cloud-init script which initializes REX-Ray docker plugin(A service which uses AWS credentials on its configuration).
I have considered the following methods. However, these methods have some disadvantages.

1. Hard code access key/secret key in cloud-init script.

   Problem: This is not secure.
2. Create IAM role, then refer access key, secret key from instance meta data.

   Problem: Access key will expires in a certain period. 
           So I need to restart REX-Ray daemon process, which causes service temporary unavailable.

Please tell me which is better way to refer access key/secret key, or another way if it exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you saying the access key expires for a IAM role?

Comment: Sorry for my english was bad. In the above (2), I want to access key/secret key from instance meta data(e.g. "http://169.254/169.254/.../security-credentials"). According to the document below, returned credential is expires at "Expiration" field. "http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials

Comment: The docker plugin should get the credentials automatically. You don't have to do anything. Is the plugin using AWS CLI or any of the AWS SDK? What is it written in?

Comment: Docker plugin(rexray volume plugin) is written in golang, and AWS credentials is passed via environment variable, or configuration file of REX-Ray. In order to get credentials from instance metadata url, plugin is need to know "IAM role name". However, there is no field corresponding to "IAM role name". So I think rexray plugin does not cares credentials expiration.  As you said, I think credentials expiration should care plugin side too.

Comment: Do not set any environment variables for AWS credentials. It should work. The script will get the credentials automatically from the meta data server. Can you try?

Comment: Yes, I can try. I have comment out the AWS credentials from rexray config, and restarted rexray daemon process. I will wait for next expiration(20 hours later), so please wait next reply for awhile. Although credential setting was commented out, currently rexray plugin is able to list the EBS volumes. So it seems rexray plugin was fetch credentials from instance meta data(using own IAM role).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker plugin should get the credentials automatically. You don't have to do anything. Do not set any environment variables for AWS credentials.

`AWS CLI` / `AWS SDK` will get the credentials automatically from the meta data server.

Comment: As you said, I have confirmed that access key / secret key has expired and refreshed automatically, and then rexray daemon process(docker plugin) still 
available to access EBS volumes. I have understand that AWS API client(docker plugin) takes care credential life cycle, so we don't need to
care about it. I will accept this method to manage credentials. Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method of authentication

**Environment variables**

Export both access and secret keys in environment environment as follow:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="anaccesskey"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="asecretkey"
```

**Shared Credential file**

You can use an AWS credentials file to specify your credentials. The default location is $HOME/.aws/credentials on Linux and OS X, or "%USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials" for Windows users. If terraform fail to detect credentials inline, or in the environment, Terraform will check this location

You can optionally specify a different location in the configuration by providing the shared_credentials_file attribute as follow

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "/Users/tf_user/.aws/creds"
  profile                 = "customprofile"
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In order to define environment variables or use "~/.aws/credentials" file, 
I think it will need create a file or define environment variables at boot time.
However, to create a file(e.g. "~/.aws/credentials") file or define environment variables(e.g. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) at boot time,
it will need to prepare cloud-init script(or shell script), and hard code values such as secret key(It seems not secure).
So I want to know the way to avoid hard coding credentials if it exists(Terraform could handle this well?).

Comment: Yes you can use EC2 role (and it the recommended way to do it). Just create an IAM role and attach it to your instance and that is it. Terraform will just ask the metadata API endpoint for credentials everytime it runs. But note  that the credential are rotated but terraform will always get a new one everytime it needs to run. this is how to create IAM role for EC2 here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have understand that even the access key / secret key from EC2 role(via instance meta data) is expired,
AWS SDK(Docker plugin uses it internally) cares its life cycle. So we don't need to care credential's life cycle(and this is recommended way).